# Woocommerce Stars Rating Save file location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rating-system

I just want to know where does the data of the ratings (stars) goes? https://prnt.sc/hn4vcd . Is it saved on a database or a json file?
I am going to transfer reviews from one site to another. I noticed that reviews are saved in the comments. However, the ratings is not in the wp_comments database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the reviews are saved in the  wp_comments table and ratings (star ratings ) are saved in the wp_commentmeta table. Column Name is meta_key and meta key Name for the star rating is "rating". https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3044102/442f367c3fea4d4ca8cc9784cbf7c5f4

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!